# how we can have a look up allows to select multiple records?

Tags: lookup-field

Can someone PLEASE tell me how I can create a lookup field that will allow the user to select multiple records from the object that the lookup field is looking up to?
I have to custom Object which has look-up field, but only can select one option while I need to be able to select multiple options.

Answer (score 1):

By definition, a lookup field in the schema is a field of type ID and is uni-valued.  You can't stuff multiple lookup object Ids into a single lookup field

Now, if you're willing to build a LWC, you could create a custom search that returned multiple records and said LWC could decide what to do with the results, perhaps distributing them across multiple lookup fields or a single lookup field across multiple records

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the other answer -
By definition, a lookup field in the schema is a field of type ID and is uni-valued. You can't stuff multiple lookup object Ids into a single lookup field.

And looking at your usecase it looks like a case where you want to related multiple records of object 1 with multiple records of object 2 and vice-a-versa. It looks like a good candidate to use junction object where in you can have lookup relationship with both the objects (object 1 and object 2) and based on the need, both these fields can be populated.